# Linux, static lib referring to other static lib within an executable

Tags: c++, linux, static, linker

I am creating an application, which consists of two static libs and an executable.

Let's call the two static libs:
libusefulclass.a
libcore.a

And the application:
myapp

libcore instantiates and uses the class defined in libusefulclass (let's call it UsefulClass)

Now, if I link the application in the following way:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.4/lib -o myapp src1.o src2.o srcN.o -lusefulclass -lcore
```

The linker complains about the methods in libusefulclass not being found:

```
undefined reference to `UsefulClass::foo()'
```

etc.

I found a workaround for this:
If UsefulClass is also instantiated within the source files of the executable itself, the application is linked without any problems.

My question is: is there a more clean way to make libcore refer to methods defined in libusefulclass, or static libs just cannot be linked against eachother?

TIA

P.S.: In case that matters: the application is being developed in C++ using Qt, but I feel this is not a Qt problem, but a library problem in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the libraries in reverse order of dependencies, so use

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.4/lib -o myapp src1.o src2.o srcN.o  -lcore -lusefulclass
```

If there's a cyclic dependency, you might even need to specify the library twice,

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.4/lib -o myapp src1.o src2.o srcN.o  -lusefulclass -lcore -lusefulclass
```

Comment: Thank you, nos, this indeed fixed it.

(Remark: for me it would seem more logical the other way round, i.e. that usefulclass preceedes core, if core depends on usefulclass... I'll keep in mind the above mentioned rule, though :)

Comment: the linker reads the symbol from the archive and discards anything noone references yet, then the next library comes along and need symbols that the linker already discarded - so you'll have to provide them in the "reverse" order